# Make responsive CSS styles

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

How could I make these styles responsive to all mobile devices?

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: #0066cc; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #0066cc 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0066cc 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0066cc 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 0.001px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #0066cc;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 15px;
    color: #000000; text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 15px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #0066cc;
        }
```

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 3):

You Need Bootstrap for making it responsive.You can learn it here: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-responsive-layout.php